# Loop data from JSON and put into another function in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want to loop the data from json and put the result into another function in controller.

function to get the json format

```
public function getApiSuperSpring() {
    //  Initiate curl
    $service_url="http://obd.id-clouds.net/raja_engine/GPS2.php?CMD=GETVEHICLE&APIKEY=1234&DOMAIN=@1111";
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //execute the session
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    //finish off the session
    curl_close($curl);

    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,TRUE);

    $arr = $decoded['VEHICLE']['DATA']; 

    $encoded = json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    $decoded_again = json_decode($encoded, TRUE);


    $data = array();
    foreach($decoded_again as $item) { 
         array_push($data, $item['LATITUDE'].','.$item['LONGITUDE']);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

JSON Result from function above.

```
array(27) { 
    [0]=> string(18) "-6.261616,106.8098" 
    [1]=> string(17) "-6.26162,106.8101" 
    [2]=> string(18) "-6.140062,106.8314" 
    [3]=> string(18) "-6.175796,106.8762" 
    [4]=> string(18) "-6.257237,106.8226"
    [5]=> string(18) "-6.324639,106.8879" 
    [6]=> string(18) "-6.256825,106.8229" 
    [7]=> string(18) "-6.139688,106.8313" 
    [8]=> string(18) "-6.221396,106.9848" 
    [9]=> string(18) "-6.566057,106.7637"
    [10]=> string(18) "-6.180055,106.8224" 
    [11]=> string(18) "-6.220346,106.9223" 
    [12]=> string(18) "-6.233933,106.8254" 
    [13]=> string(18) "-6.369154,106.8271" 
    [14]=> string(18) "-6.210821,106.8166"
    [15]=> string(18) "-6.224951,106.8282" 
    [16]=> string(17) "-6.219806,106.813" 
    [17]=> string(17) "-6.243915,106.891" 
    [18]=> string(17) "-6.20253,106.8249" 
    [19]=> string(18) "-6.398064,106.8533"
    [20]=> string(17) "-6.39802,106.8537" 
    [21]=> string(18) "-6.228237,106.8252" 
    [22]=> string(18) "-6.150562,106.7151"
    [23]=> string(18) "-6.142435,106.7061" 
    [24]=> string(18) "-6.169276,106.9115"
    [25]=> string(18) "-6.193656,106.8788" 
    [26]=> string(18) "-6.345975,106.8228" }
```

What result that i want is like below

```
Coordinate 1 : -6.261616,106.8098
Coordinate 2 : -6.26162,106.8101 
Coordinate 3 : -6.140062,106.8314
..
Coordinate 26 : 6.345975,106.8228
```

How to pass that json result into above format.

Comment: Looks like you have takes some fairly organised information and turned it into stuff. How do you know if `array  [5]=> string(18) "-6.324639,106.8879"` is a latitude or a longitude

Comment: @RiggsFolly : earlier that array format i use for a line on googlemaps api, i will create another json format, but how to loop to other function if the format is lat long only ?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks in advance for the manual, i just change my question and what is my expected result from that json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got clue by myself.

```
public function abc() {

    $result_array = $this->getApiSuperSpring();

    $marker = array();

            foreach($result_array as $item) { 
                echo 'Coordinate'. $item.'<br>';
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your custom helper and put getApiSuperSpring this function in it and call this helper in any controller you want i think its not big stuff with codeignitor

Comment: may i got some example ?